# Uncaught IndexSizeError when querying a websql table

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I'm querying a websql table on "keyup" so it returns a list of the first 10 matches of the string queried, I hold this search string in a variable called `currval` which I pass into the query string.

When my results set is equal to 1 row, i.e an exact match I get the following error:

Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'item' on 'SQLResultSetRowList': The index provided (1) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (1).

My table looks like:

```
id |  name
```

and contains 2500 rows.

Heres the query:

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM classes WHERE name LIKE '"+currval+"%' ", 
[], function (tx, results) {
      var len = results.rows.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          var item = results.rows.item(i);
          var name = item.name;

          $('#classnameresults').append('<li class="classnameitem">'+name+'</li>');
      }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't that be

```
...
for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(len, 10); i++) {
```

otherwise if the number of results are less than 10 it will give an error trying to access a non-existent item.